# How can I add space to the end of a TextBlock in XAML? (Windows 10, UWP)

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-10, uwp

`Text="Some text:"` I want to add a space after the colon.

I've tried `xml:space="preserve"` and `&#160;` but neither seems to work.

I know it can be done by adding margin, but I'm curious if there's another way.

Comment: Can you explain exactly you you are trying to do. Can you not just add right margin to the TextBlock?

Comment: Do you try to add some extra white space after the text in a textblock?

Comment: A space is just an " " in xaml...

Comment: PLZ PLZ PLZ add some code here ! you question is meaningless.

Comment: Yes, I can add margin to it, but I'm curious, if there is another way.

Comment: There is a solution in this Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622034/how-to-preserve-white-spaces-of-textblock-in-uwp-apps

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this, it works for me.

```
<RelativePanel>
    <TextBlock x:Name="test1" RelativePanel.Below="edLongitude">
        ahoj &#160;  
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="test2" RelativePanel.Below="edLongitude" RelativePanel.RightOf="test1" Text="nazdar" />
</RelativePanel>
```

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is using `Run`:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="Black">
    <Run Text="SomeText:"/>
    <Run/>
</TextBlock>
```

The `Run` element on a new line will add the space, but if you write the two Runs on the same line, the space will not be created:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="Black">
    <Run Text="SomeText:"/><Run/>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: That's the most reliable approach, I think.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest thing would just be applying a margin - any reason you can't do that?

```
<TextBlock Text="MyText" Margin="0 0 8 0" />
```

Comment: Doesn't help when it's multi-line.