# How to preserve white-spaces of TextBlock in UWP apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

If you simply set the value of Text property in a TextBlock as "**Example**   " (Note that there 3 whitespaces at the **end** of this string),what TextBlock shows in UI is just "**Example**".

And after searching for solutions on the Internet, I found that there is a way to solve this issue:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" 
        BorderBrush="#FFFF0202" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock x:Name="t1">
        <Run Text="Example&#160;&#160;&#160;"/>
    </TextBlock>
</Border>
```

The above code shows the use of Inline Property of TextBlock and `&#160;` in Run's Text displays the whitespace correctly.

However, im my case I need to set the Text property of TextBlock in **Code-behind(or via DataBinding)**, the trick above doesn't work and it shows **`Example&#160;&#160;&#160;`** in UI.

I tried to set the value of Run's Text property by data binding, which I think can displays the escape character correctly, but Run's Text property is NOT a dependency property so I have no better way to solve this.

(However I think use padding property of TextBlock is also a trick to do this, and it should work. But there is any better way to do ?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, `Run.Text` *does* support data binding.

The reason that `&#160;` doesn't print correctly inside data binding is because it's using XML escape characters.

Try using `(char)160` instead -

```
public string TestString { get; set; } = "Example" + (char)160 + (char)160 + (char)160;

<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{x:Bind TestString}" />
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 4):

The [zero width no-break space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) is treated as a non-printing character instead of whitespace, so adding `&#xfeff;` to the end of your value in XAML will preserve trailing spaces:

```xml
<Run Text="Example&#160;&#160;&#160;&#xfeff;"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try setting the `xml:space` property to preserve in your XAML

```
<TextBox Name="t1"
         xml:space="preserve"
         Text="Example   " />
```

Comment: If you do `<TextBlock><Run>Hello</Run><Run xml:space="preserve"> world!</Run></TextBlock>` the space between *Hello* and *world* is preserved if and only if the `xml:space` attribute is set. So xml:space="preserve" does work in UWP but it is indeed not propagated from the TextBlock to Run as expected.  
I guess the most relevant documentation on this is MSDN's [Whitespace Processing in XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788746%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I have recently installed Visual Studio 2017 and noticed that the bug was fixed and now `xml:space="preserve"` works as documented: you can have it specified on any parent of the `<Run>` element such as `<TextBlock>` or even `<Page ...>` and this will stop white space trimming and collapsing inside the `<Run>`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for a Listview.ItemTemplate in UWP.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <TextBlock xml:space="preserve"><Run Text="{Binding ID}"></Run><Run> </Run><Run Text="{Binding name}"></Run><Run> </Run><Run Text="{Binding ipAdress}"></Run></TextBlock>
           </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

- Please note that the text block has the attribute xml:space="preserve".
- The spaces are set with run elements `<Run> </Run>`.
- With this solution you have to make sure that the  and the  elements are defined on once line in the code editor, otherwise the free space contained in there, will be taken over.