# Unable to activate Windows Store app 'Operation not supported'

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to convert a char array to a string, and put the string in a TextBlock.
The specific line '_textBl.Text = word;' makes my program unable to run, here's the whole code.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        int _currentIndex;
        string _currentWord;
        string[] _strArr = { "ant", "bee", "spider", "mosquito" };
        int _difficulty = 1;
        public MainPage()
        {
        Random rnd = new Random();
            _currentIndex = rnd.Next(0, 5);

            foreach (char c in _strArr[_currentIndex])
            {
                _currentWord = _strArr[_currentIndex];
                string _temp = _currentWord;
                char[] _wordArr = _currentWord.ToCharArray();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                for (int i = 0; i < _wordArr.Length; i++)
                {
                    _wordArr[i] = '_';
                }
                string word = new string(_wordArr);
                _textBl.Text = word;

            }
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can't access the textbox `_textB1` before the call to `InitializeComponent`.  Try moving that line after the call.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway first of all, thanks a lot for clarifying that! thing is, when I moved that line after `this.InitializeComponent();` it didn't identify `string word`. should I just move everything after `public MainPage()`? btw, is there a simple way to implement spaces between each char after the convertion to string?

Comment: I don't see any reason not to move the `InitializeComponent` call to the first line of the constructor as you proposed.  I think it should work.  As to your second question, I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway  Thanks a lot, about my second question- I managed to make my idea work(basically adding spaces to the converted string between each of its chars - like a proper Hangman game. perhaps could've been done more efficiently though: https://i.imgur.com/gjfKPND.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could to insert the spaces in your string with [`(char)160`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32623966/7254781), I simplified your code like the following.

**Please note** the `_strArr` implemented only has 4 items, if you make rnd.Next(0, 5), it will cause access out of range issue.

```
 int _currentIndex;
 string _currentWord;
 string[] _strArr = { "ant", "bee", "spider", "mosquito" };
 int _difficulty = 1;
 Random rnd = new Random();
 _currentIndex = rnd.Next(0, 4);

 foreach (char c in _strArr[_currentIndex])
 {
     _currentWord = _strArr[_currentIndex];
     string rest = string.Empty;
     foreach (var item in _currentWord)
     {
         rest += "_" + (char)160;
     }

     MyTb.Text = rest;        
 }
```

Comment: **"Please note the _strArr implemented only has 4 items, if you make rnd.Next(0, 5), it will cause access out of range issue."** yep while experimenting with it for a bit I understood it by myself but thanks :D also I removed some useless variables I had inside the foreach loop and shortened it to 14 lines but yours is much more efficient using 7 lines so I'm gonna read it and understand what u did, thanks a lot :)